# Powershell: Specify files by the day they were created on

Tags: powershell

I want to select the files that are made on (for example) the `9th day` in every month in a directory.

I came up with this code:

```
dir -Recurse -File | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime.Day -eq "09"}
```

However, this gives me every file made on every day in that directory.

I can't see why this doesn't work.
Hope someone can help me out!

Comment: ..works for me though.. Since the `.Day` returns an integer, you should really not compare it with a string so PowerShell does not have to cast it into an int. Maybe you are confusing the `LastWriteTime` (which you see in Explorer) with `CreationTime` ?

Comment: @Theo It does work with LastWriteTime, but that's not what I want to specify this search to. They have to be created on the day I give in.

Comment: Ok, but then remember that the CreationTime may have been altered after a copy action. For instance, if you copy a few items from their original location (where they will have different creation times) to a new destination, the `CreationTime` for all of these items will be set to the current time. Maybe that is why your original code returns them all?

Comment: `dir -Recurse -File | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime.Day -eq 9} | fl Name,CreationTime,LastAccessTime,LastWriteTime` this works fine for me, returns only the results for anything created on the 9th day.

Comment: @Jacob Your comment works the best, but because you put it as a comment and not as an answer, i can't mark the question as answered. Could you repost you comment as an answer please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to reiterate what TheIncorrigle1 stated, this was likely caused by some casting oddity with the String `"09"` and the int `9` as I couldn't reproduce the issue (your original code snippet posted worked fine for me).

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime.Day -eq 9} | Format-List Name,CreationTime,LastAccessTime,LastWriteTime
```

The above returns only the results for anything created on the 9th day and explicitly lists the `Name, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime`

```
PS C:\Testing> Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime.Day -eq 9} | Format-List Name,CreationTime,LastAccessTime,LastWriteTime


Name           : csv.txt
CreationTime   : 09/07/2018 17:37:13
LastAccessTime : 09/07/2018 17:37:13
LastWriteTime  : 23/07/2018 22:41:36
```

Answer (score 0):

I *suspect* this is because of your comparison operator (although I couldn't replicate your problem in the first place).  Since the `Day` property is an integer, you should compare with like types:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $PSItem.CreationTime.Day -eq 9 }
```

Otherwise, you're at the mercy of the type-casting system to compare a string and integer properly.